# Clarification on basic (horizontal) differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Here's a question from Lee's Smooth Manifolds (Exercise 12-9) which was more or less answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69758/192336). The question is this:

> Let $\pi:M\to N$ be a smooth surjective submersion between smooth manifolds $M,N$ such that each fiber is connected. A tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ is vertical if $d\pi_p(v)=0$. Suppose $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$. Show that there exists $\eta\in\Omega^k(N)$ such that $\omega=\pi^{\ast}\eta$ if and only if $i_v\omega_p=0$ and $i_vd\omega_p=0$ for all $p\in M$ and vertical $v\in T_pM$. [Hint:first do the case in which $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a projection onto the first $n$ coordinates].

So the forward direction ($\omega=\pi^{\ast}\eta\Rightarrow$etc.) is a straightforward computation. However, the other implication is not at all clear. I could see how the hint could help in the general case, since we ought to be able to choose coordinates so that we can reduce to this case locally and glue it together to get some sort of global result with partitions of unity. However, even in this simplest case I'm not sure where to go.

The linked answer does provide a sketch of the proof, although I don't understand it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if you have $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $y\in\Bbb R^m$, and $\pi(x,y)=x$, write your $k$-form $\omega = \omega_1 + \omega_2$, where $\omega_1$ has terms built out of only $dx_i$'s and $\omega_2$ has at least one $dy_j$ in each term. Use the first condition to show that $\omega_2=0$. If a general term of $\omega_1$ is of the form $f(x,y)dx_I$, use the second condition to show that $f(x,y)$ is independent of $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{ x_i\}$ is a coordinate for $N$ and we can extend it so that $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n\cup \{ y_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is a coodrinate for $M$.

Consider a coordinate vector field $\{ E_i\}_{i=1}^{n}\cup \{F_i\}_{i=1}^m $ at $p$ s,t, $ \{ F_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is tangent to a fiber.

Then any form $k$-form $\omega$ has a deomposition : $ \omega_1$ is a wedge product of $E_i^\ast$ and $\omega_2$ contains at least one $F_i^\ast$ so that $$ \omega=\omega_1+ \omega_2 $$

S0 $$ i_v \omega =i_v\omega_2=0\Rightarrow \omega_2=0$$

Let $$\omega = \sum_{i_j<i_{j+1}} f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x,y) E_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge E_{i_k} $$

Then $$ d\omega = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x,y) E_i^\ast \wedge E_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge E_{i_k}  + \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}
f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x,y) F_i^\ast \wedge E_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge E_{i_k}  $$

Since $i_vd\omega =0 $ then $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}
f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x,y) =0 \Rightarrow f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x,y) =f_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x) $$

Comment: Why does this work globally? It seems to me that this shows that $\omega$ is locally the pullback of something locally defined in the base space. However, I don't understand how this can be extended to a global solution.

Comment: @AndrewV now you can select a covering $\{ U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ such that on each $U_{\alpha}$ the map $\pi$ looks like a projection, and then you select a partition of unity $\{ \rho_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}.$ Now you have $ \rho_{\alpha} \cdot \omega=\pi^{*}(\eta_{\alpha}).$ Now you observe that the sum $\sum_{\alpha} \eta_{\alpha}$ is well defined, because only a finite number of terms is non zero.

Comment: @AndrewV Finally you verify that $\sum_{\alpha}\eta_{\alpha}$ has the property of being pulled back to $\omega.$
Again you have exploit the fact that the sum is locally finite and that the pullback is linear.