# Restrict differential forms that vanish along fibres to the base

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology

I am reading Jean-Luc Brylinski's book on loop space. At the end of section 1.6 *Leray Spectral Sequence*, he claims without proof that

> Let $f: Y\to X$ be a smooth bundle of paracompact manifolds. A $p$-form $\omega$ on $Y$ is called *basic* if it satisfies:
>
> For any vertical vector field $\xi$ on $Y$,
>
> 1. $i(\xi)\omega =0$;
> 2. $i(\xi)\mathrm{d} \omega =0.$
>
> Assume the fiber $F$ is connected, then $f^*$ identifies space of smooth $p$-forms $A^p(X)$ with space of basic $p$-forms on $Y$.

I wonder whether it can be proved by Cartan homotopy formula.

More precisely, given $\omega$ basic, define $\eta (x_0) =\omega (x_0, z)$ for $(x_0,z)\in f^{-1}(x_0)$. Choose a local coordinate we see that $\omega$ has no *fiber* components.

Since $L_{\gamma '(t)}\omega =0$ for path in $f^{-1}(x_0)$, it is well-defined.

Does this work? The following are some info that I thought might help.

A somewhat related post is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201031/differential-forms-along-the-fiber).

Brylinski also describes basic forms in language of *Cartan filtration* $F^k$, which is subcomplexes of $A^{\bullet}(Y)$ where $F^k(A^n(Y))$ consists of those $n$-forms $\omega$ such that for any vertical vector fields $\xi _1, \cdots ,\xi _{n-k+1}$,
$$i(\xi _1)\cdots i(\xi _{n-k+1})\omega=0.$$

I looked up some related books. Brylinski referred *Cartan filtration* to Cartan's article *La transgression dans un groupe de Lie et dans un fibré principal* .

The same filtration appears in Akio Hattori's paper *Spectral Sequence in the de Rham Cohomology of fibre bundles*, in which Hattori referred that filtration to

1. Leray *L'anneau spectral et l'anneau filtré d'homologie d'un espace localement compact et d'une application continue*
2. Serre *Homologie singulière Des espace fibrés*

But I can hardly read French.

Comment: See also this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69658/basic-differential-forms

Comment: @studiosus Thank you so much!